# XSL not processing correctly in DataPower

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

> I have a wired problem with DataPower now, it's not processing an XML
>   transformation properly. With the below input:
>
> ```
>     <response status="200"><CustomELearningVO><ClassListVO>         
>     <CLASS_TAB_OBJ>
>     <CLASS_TAB>
>     <CLASS_OBJ>
>     <ClassId>123456</ClassId>
>     <ClassName>Sample Class1</ClassName>
>     <Status>Not Attempted</Status>
>     <Link>link</Link>
>     <PlayEnable>Y</PlayEnable>
>     </CLASS_OBJ>
>
>     <CLASS_OBJ>
>     <ClassId>56789</ClassId>
>     <ClassName>Sample Class2</ClassName>
>     <Status>Failed</Status>
>     <Link>link2</Link><PlayEnable>Y</PlayEnable>
>     </CLASS_OBJ>
>
>     <CLASS_OBJ>
>     <ClassId>56788</ClassId>
>     <ClassName>Sample Class3</ClassName>
>     <Status>Failed</Status>
>     <PlayEnable>N</PlayEnable>
>     <PlayMessage>"Course cannot be played as Certfication subscribed to Course has Expired"</PlayMessage>
>     </CLASS_OBJ>
>
>     </CLASS_TAB>
>     </CLASS_TAB_OBJ>
>     </ClassListVO><eBSErrorCode>0</eBSErrorCode><eBSErrorMessage>SUCCESS</eBSErrorMessage></CustomELearningVO></response>
>
>
> When I use the below XSL, it process properly and gives me a correct output (output1). But the same gives a different output
> ```
>
> (output2) when I put it into Datapower.
>
> ```
>     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
> ```
>
> xmlns:wsdl="http://api.esr.nhs.uk/v1/ELearning/wsdl"
>   xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
>   xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
>   extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="wsdl soap
>   dp">
>
> ```
>         <xsl:template match="/">
>             <xsl:if test="/response/CustomELearningVO/ClassListVO/CLASS_TAB_OBJ/CLASS_TAB/CLASS_OBJ/ClassId">
>                 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
>                     <soap:Header>
>                     <callerIds>
>                             <userId>
>                                 <xsl:value-of select="1234"/>
>                             </userId>
>                             <responsibilityId>
>                                 <xsl:value-of select="576"/>
>                             </responsibilityId>
>                         </callerIds>
>                         <requestId>
>                             <xsl:value-of select="123"/>
>                         </requestId>
>                         <sessionToken>
>                             <xsl:value-of select="8787"/>
>                         </sessionToken>
>                     </soap:Header>
>                     <soap:Body>
>                         <wsdl:getELearningClassResponse>
>                                     <xsl:apply-templates select="/response/CustomELearningVO/ClassListVO/CLASS_TAB_OBJ/CLASS_TAB/CLASS_OBJ[ClassId]"/>
>                         </wsdl:getELearningClassResponse>
>                     </soap:Body>
>                 </soap:Envelope>
>             </xsl:if>
>
>             <xsl:if test="not(/response/CustomELearningVO/ClassListVO/CLASS_TAB_OBJ/CLASS_TAB/CLASS_OBJ/ClassId)">
>                 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
>                     <soap:Body>
>                         <soap:Fault>
>                             <soap:Code>
>                                 <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
>                                 <soap:Subcode>
>                                     <soap:Value>soap:INT1001</soap:Value>
>                                 </soap:Subcode>
>                             </soap:Code>
>                             <soap:Reason>
>                                 <soap:Text xml:lang="en">
>                                     <xsl:value-of select="/response/CustomELearningVO/eBSErrorMessage"/>
>                                 </soap:Text>
>                             </soap:Reason>
>                         </soap:Fault>
>                     </soap:Body>
>                 </soap:Envelope>
>             </xsl:if>
>         </xsl:template>
>
>
>
>     <xsl:template match="/response/CustomELearningVO/ClassListVO/CLASS_TAB_OBJ/CLASS_TAB/CLASS_OBJ">
>     <learningClass>
>                 <classId><xsl:value-of select="ClassId"/></classId>
>                 <className><xsl:value-of select="ClassName"/></className>
>                 <status><xsl:value-of select="Status"/></status>
>                 <link><xsl:value-of select="Link"/></link>
>                 <playEnable><xsl:value-of select="PlayEnable"/></playEnable>
>                 <playMessage><xsl:value-of select="PlayMessage"/></playMessage>        
>     </learningClass>
>     </xsl:template>
>
>     </xsl:stylesheet>
> ```
>
> output1 (Processed in Notepad++)
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
>   <soap:Header>
>     <callerIds>
>       <userId>1234</userId>
>       <responsibilityId>576</responsibilityId>
>     </callerIds>
>     <requestId>123</requestId>
>     <sessionToken>8787</sessionToken>
>   </soap:Header>
>   <soap:Body>
>     <wsdl:getELearningClassResponse xmlns:wsdl="http://api.esr.nhs.uk/v1/ELearning/wsdl">
>       <learningClass>
>         <classId>123456</classId>
>         <className>Sample Class1</className>
>         <status>Not Attempted</status>
>         <link>link</link>
>         <playEnable>Y</playEnable>
>         <playMessage/>
>       </learningClass>
>       <learningClass>
>         <classId>56789</classId>
>         <className>Sample Class2</className>
>         <status>Failed</status>
>         <link>link2</link>
>         <playEnable>Y</playEnable>
>         <playMessage/>
>       </learningClass>
>       <learningClass>
>         <classId>56788</classId>
>         <className>Sample Class3</className>
>         <status>Failed</status>
>         <link/>
>         <playEnable>N</playEnable>
>         <playMessage>"Course cannot be played as Certfication subscribed to Course has Expired"</playMessage>
>       </learningClass>
>     </wsdl:getELearningClassResponse>
>   </soap:Body>
> </soap:Envelope>
> ```
>
> output2 (Processed in DP)
>
> ```
> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
>    <soap:Body>
>       <soap:Fault>
>          <soap:Code>
>             <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
>             <soap:Subcode>
>                <soap:Value>soap:INT1001</soap:Value>
>             </soap:Subcode>
>          </soap:Code>
>          <soap:Reason>
>             <soap:Text xml:lang="en">SUCCESS</soap:Text>
>          </soap:Reason>
>       </soap:Fault>
>    </soap:Body>
> </soap:Envelope>
> ```
>
> Can anyone suggest, what the problem here? Or am I making any
>   mistakes?
>
> **PartII**
>
> Updated the XSL a bit:
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="/">
>     <xsl:if test="(/response/CustomELearningVO/ClassListVO)">
>         <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
>             <soap:Header>
>             <callerIds>
>                     <userId>
>                         <xsl:value-of select="1234"/>
>                     </userId>
>                     <responsibilityId>
>                         <xsl:value-of select="576"/>
>                     </responsibilityId>
>                 </callerIds>
>                 <requestId>
>                     <xsl:value-of select="123"/>
>                 </requestId>
>                 <sessionToken>
>                     <xsl:value-of select="8787"/>
>                 </sessionToken>
>             </soap:Header>
>             <soap:Body>
>                 <wsdl:getELearningClassResponse>
>                             <xsl:apply-templates select="/response/CustomELearningVO/ClassListVO/CLASS_TAB_OBJ/CLASS_TAB/CLASS_OBJ[ClassId]"/>
>                 </wsdl:getELearningClassResponse>
>             </soap:Body>
>         </soap:Envelope>
>     </xsl:if>
>
>     <xsl:if test="not(/response/CustomELearningVO)">
>         <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
>             <soap:Body>
>                 <soap:Fault>
>                     <soap:Code>
>                         <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
>                         <soap:Subcode>
>                             <soap:Value>soap:INT1001</soap:Value>
>                         </soap:Subcode>
>                     </soap:Code>
>                     <soap:Reason>
>                         <soap:Text xml:lang="en">
>                             <xsl:value-of select="/response/CustomELearningVO/eBSErrorMessage"/>
>                         </soap:Text>
>                     </soap:Reason>
>                 </soap:Fault>
>             </soap:Body>
>         </soap:Envelope>
>     </xsl:if>
>
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> But now its printing upto the apply template part:
>
> ```
>  <soap:Envelope
>     xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
>     >
>
>         <soap:Header>
>             <callerIds>
>                 <userId>1234</userId>
>                 <responsibilityId>576</responsibilityId>
>             </callerIds>
>             <requestId>123</requestId>
>             <sessionToken>8787</sessionToken>
>         </soap:Header>
>         <soap:Body>
>             <wsdl:getELearningClassResponse
>             xmlns:wsdl="http://api.esr.nhs.uk/v1/ELearning/wsdl"
>             />
>         </soap:Body>
>
>     </soap:Envelope>
> ```
>
> Which means its not understanding this part:
>
> ```
> <xsl:apply-templates select="/response/CustomELearningVO/ClassListVO/CLASS_TAB_OBJ/CLASS_TAB/CLASS_OBJ[ClassId]"/>
> ```
>
> Can anyone help me to understand how can I print the rest of the
>   message?

Comment: We probably must see how you put the xslt into the datapower. You probably do not output the result of the xslt transform.

Comment: I an getting the output after the transform as output2 above. Which means it goes to the 2nd condition from the xsl "<xsl:if test="not(/response/CustomELearningVO/ClassListVO/CLASS_TAB_OBJ/CLASS_TAB/CLASS_OBJ/ClassId)">". But in notepad it gives the output as output1.

Comment: I see, sorry, tldr - so the question boils down to that it seems that dp evaluates the long xpath check `/response/Cus..._OBJ/ClassId` different? - btw I would suggest to make a xsl:choose/xsl:when/xsl:otherwise out of that, coz this way it is it looks like it might generate two root elements in the output if the two xsl:if's aren't exactly exclusive.

Comment: Tried that as well, but no luck.

Comment: This is quite long, you *might* have more chance to get an answer by boiling it down to a [Minimum Complete Verifyable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  (sometimes in this process the error is even found yourself)